# How to call method of another function without prototyping

Tags: javascript

This is surely trivial question, but I am little confused with JavaScript. I want to call method inside another function. I have spent some time to handle this and all I have got so far is the second piece of code. I would like to know, if there is any similar solution as noted in comment.

```
function Student() {
  this.greeting = function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m student.');
  };
};

function Teacher() {
  Student.call(this)
  this.greeting = function() {
    Student.???  // here I want something like "inherited", or call  Student.greeting()
    alert('and I like apples');
  };
};
```

I want to be sure, there is no another option like prototyping:

```
function Student() {

};

Student.prototype.greeting = function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m student.');
  };

function Teacher() {
  Student.call(this);
  this.greeting = function() {
    Student.prototype.greeting();
        alert('and I like apples');
  };
};
```

Thanx

Comment: This looks like you're trying to use shadowing with class inheritance which is not in the spirit of JavaScript which uses the prototype chain for linking objects. By delegating to other objects (using Object.create for example) you can access these methods through `[[Prototype]]' chaining.

Answer (score -1):

Student is a function, in your case it is also a constructor.
To call "Student" you need to save object returned by call of constructor-function Student

```
function Teacher() {
  var stdnt = new Student()
  this.greeting = function() {
    stdnt.greeting()
    alert('and I like apples');
  };
};
```

Also, in your code Student.call(this) is equivalent to just function call Student() - without creation of new object

Upd2. This call of stdnt from inner function called "closure"

Comment: So the the only possibility is to instantiate Student function?

Comment: In your example, greeting is a member function of student

Comment: Except your variant? Yes, you have to instantiate new object by calling Student constructor. Of cause there can be other ways, for example like this

Comment: the "call" function will take properties (there are none now) from Student and then I can use them in the Teacher. But I can not do the same with function (method)... and that is frustrating...

Comment: var Student = {greeting: function (){alert("Student"}}

Comment: No call will not take props from Student. It will be vice versa

Comment: What call function is actually do is setup current context inside Student function for this particular case. In your case this context inside Student function will be equal to context of Teacher function, as you pass context of Teacher ("this") to it

Comment: Thanx. Javascript is sometimes pretty tricky... :-)

Comment: @Paul greeting is not a member of function Student. It a member of context passed to Student